# How can I collectively select 100 rows from 3 different tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables containing similar rows of data.
I need to select 100 rows from all of the three tables with the following conditions:

No more than 25 rows can be selected from Table A --> (name it count_a)

No more than 40 rows can be selected from Table B --> (count_b)

Any number of rows can be selected from Table C (count_c) but the number should be 
   count_c = 100 - (count_a + count_b)

[image: Combine 3 tables in one collection of rows]

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE ROWNUM <= 25
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM TABLE_B WHERE ROWNUM <= 40
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM TABLE_C 
) WHERE ROWNUM <=100
```

But the query is too slow and does not always give me 100 rows.

Comment: Your query looks fine - in which cases doesn't it give 100 rows?

Comment: As you stated your conditions, they are satisfied, even if you return just the 100 rows from the table C. So here you go: SELECT * FROM TABLE_C WHERE ROWNUM <=100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `WHERE ROWNUM <= 100` to the last select:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT TABLE_A.*, 1 as OrdRow FROM TABLE_A WHERE ROWNUM <= 25
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT TABLE_B.*, 2 as OrdRow FROM TABLE_B WHERE ROWNUM <= 40
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TABLE_C.*, 3 as OrdRow  FROM TABLE_C WHERE ROWNUM <= 100
) WHERE ROWNUM <=100
  ORDER BY OrdRow;
```

Also you can try:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE ROWNUM <= 25
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B WHERE ROWNUM <= 40
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE_C WHERE ROWNUM <= 
       100
       -
       (select count(*) TABLE_A WHERE ROWNUM <= 25)
       -
       (select count(*) TABLE_B WHERE ROWNUM <= 40)
```

Comment: That did the job. and also the performance is much better. Thanks

Comment: The first query is making the unwarranted assumption that given UNION ALLs, the optimizer will always return rows from the first query, followed by the rows from the second query, etc. Sure, that's what Oracle does in practice, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp The first query isn't making such assumption. The order of UNION isn't important here. We need to return 100 rows from 3 tables so we can limit TABLE_C with 100 rows. In this case even if A ansd B return no rows C returns 100 and we will get 100 rows total.

Comment: Perhaps - I read the question a bit differently - it seems to me that he definitely wants the rows from TABLE_A and TABLE_B if any, and only fill in the remaining slots up to 100 from TABLE_C. But maybe my interpretation of the OP is incorrect.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I've reread question and I think you're right. I've updated the first query to fix this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
SELECT * FROM
(
     SELECT * FROM table_a where rownum <=25
     UNION ALL    
     SELECT * FROM table_b WHERE ROWNUM <= 40
     UNION ALL
     SELECT * FROM table_c WHERE ROWNUM <= 100 - ((SELECT count(*) FROM table_a WHERE ROWNUM <= 25) + (SELECT count(*) FROM table_b WHERE ROWNUM <= 40))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you'd have to do something like this in order to guarantee that you'll always get rows from TABLE_A and TABLE_B if they exist:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 'A' t, TABLE_A.* FROM TABLE_A WHERE ROWNUM <= 25
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'B' t, TABLE_B.* FROM TABLE_B WHERE ROWNUM <= 40
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C' t, TABLE_C.* FROM TABLE_C 
  ) ORDER BY t
) WHERE ROWNUM <= 100;
```

This is because the optimizer is *allowed* to run the subqueries in any order it likes - e.g. in parallel.

With regard to performance, I suspect that the sort op will not add too much time to the execution time because it's only sorting a maximum of 100 rows anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ... Execution speed is a nightmare to every developer or programmer ...
In that case you can try like ... i think it will speed up your query more

```
DECLARE @Table_A_Row_Count INT, @Table_B_Row_Count INT,@RemainCount INT=0

--Getting count of primary tables
SELECT @Table_A_Row_Count= COUNT(1) FROM TABLE_A
SELECT @Table_B_Row_Count= COUNT(1) FROM TABLE_B 

--Calculating remaining colections
IF @Table_A_Row_Count+@Table_B_Row_Count<100 
    BEGIN
        SET @RemainCount=100-(@Table_A_Row_Count+@Table_B_Row_Count)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        --You might do somthing like this if First
        --and second table covering 100 rows
        SET @Table_B_Row_Count=100-@Table_A_Row_Count
    END

--Finaly getting 100 rows
SELECT top @Table_A_Row_Count * FROM TABLE_A
UNION ALL 
SELECT top @Table_B_Row_Count * FROM TABLE_B
UNION ALL
SELECT Top @RemainCount * FROM TABLE_C
```

Comment: Very nice way> I like this solution. But I prefer the simplest one, I have accepted above

Comment: @MoumitMondal That's SQL server syntax, not Oracle.